# Limit of a piecewise function

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$ f(x) = {   0,}$   if $x$ is rational.
$f(x) = \sin(x)$ if $x$ is irrational.

Find the limit at $x = 0$.

Recall a similar example in a lecture where two sequences were used to solve. Not sure if this is relevant to this example and or how to solve it.

Comment: What is $\lim_{x\to 0} \sin (x)$?  What is $\lim_{x\to 0} 0$?

Comment: 0 for both i believe

Comment: Yes.  And therefore...

Comment: Limit would be 0? it feels like there should be a method to it, or is this method simply realising that both functions have the same limit at 0?

Comment: Well, you should argue that it is enough to show that the limits coincide at $0$, but this is not difficult.  For all $x$ we have $|f(x)-0|≤|\sin(x)-0|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are trying to prove that
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\:f(x) = 0$$
According to the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem), if $g(x) \le f(x) \le h(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = \lim_{x\to a} h(x) = L$, then $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L$. In our formula, we get
$$0 \le f(x) \le \sin(x)$$
when approaching from the right, and
$$\sin(x) \le f(x) \le 0$$
when approaching from the left.
Although we can continue from here, we can also write this in a format that will directly fit the format. Let's define the two piecewise functions
$$g(x) = \begin{cases} \sin(x) & \text{if $x < 0$} \\ 0 & \text{if $x \ge 0$} \end{cases}$$
$$h(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if $x \le 0$} \\ \sin(x) & \text{if $x > 0$} \end{cases}$$
This way, on an interval $x \in [-\pi, \pi],$
$$g(x) \le f(x) \le h(x)$$
meaning we may continue.
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\:g(x) = 0$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\:h(x) = 0$$
$$\therefore$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\:f(x) = 0$$
The same method can be used to prove that
$$\lim_{x\to k\pi}f(x) = 0,\, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
Although, I will leave you to prove that if you wish.